# In onResume() method.when I put "mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);", it causes unfortunately stopped while installing

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In the `onResume()` method, when I put `mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);`, it causes unfortunately stopped while installing the app. If I remove the statement, it works well but it doesn't show the sign in option. How I can overcome this error and show the sign in option in my app? The code is given below:

```
package com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
    public static final int DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT = 1000;
    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;

    private ListView mMessageListView;
    private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ImageButton mPhotoPickerButton;
    private EditText mMessageEditText;
    private Button mSendButton;

    private String mUsername;
    //variables for read and write data from  firebase
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mMessageDatabaseReference;
    private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Initialize Realtime database & database Reference

        mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mMessageDatabaseReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("messages");



        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;

        // Initialize references to views
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
        mPhotoPickerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photoPickerButton);
        mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
        mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

        // Initialize message ListView and its adapter
        List<FriendlyMessage> friendlyMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, R.layout.item_message, friendlyMessages);
        mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);

        // Initialize progress bar
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

        // ImagePickerButton shows an image picker to upload a image for a message
        mPhotoPickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO: Fire an intent to show an image picker
            }
        });

        // Enable Send button when there's text to send
        mMessageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
        mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT)});

        // Send button sends a message and clears the EditText
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO: Send messages on click

                // Clear input box
                mMessageEditText.setText("");
            }
        });
        //Send button activity set
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage=new FriendlyMessage(mMessageEditText.getText()
                        .toString(),mUsername,null);
                mMessageDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
                mMessageEditText.setText("");
            }
        });

        //Child event listener for write data from database********************

        mChildEventListener=new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage= dataSnapshot.getValue(FriendlyMessage.class);
           mMessageAdapter.add(friendlyMessage);

            }


            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        mMessageDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
        mAuthStateListener=new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                FirebaseUser user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(user !=null){
                    //sign in code
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Welcome,you are successfully logged in.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else{
                    //sign out code
                    startActivityForResult(
                            AuthUI.getInstance()
                                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                    .setProviders(
                                            AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER,
                                            AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER)
                                    .build(),
                            RC_SIGN_IN);

                }
            }
        };

        //*************************************************************************

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
           mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(mAuthStateListener!=null){

            mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never assigned a value to `mFirebaseAuth`, which means that it has the default value of `null`.  The error in logcat is going to be a NullPointerException.  You need to assign a value to `mFirebaseAuth` before using it:

```
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

Comment: I have assigned the value to mFirebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance()  in onCreate(SavedInstance) method.But,same problem occured.Plz,show me a way.